# Is there any way to automatically generate @property and @dynamic tags for Core Data primitive accessors?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

**Update: mogenerator works, with a template modification**

The Core Data documentation suggests using the -primitiveValue and -setPrimitiveValue: methods to access and change internal data of an NSManagedObject subclass rather than the slower and non-type-checked -primitiveValueForKey: and setPrimitiveValue:forKey:.

I would like to adopt this change in my code but in order to avoid compiler warnings I need to add @property and @dynamic declarations to my managed object classes for all those primitive accessors. Xcode is happy to generate all that code for me, but only for the public accessors to the object (-value rather than -primitiveValue).

Is there any automated method, either through Xcode or an external program that can scan the .xcdatamodel file, to generate those primitive accessors for me so I don't have to type them all out in all 16 of my managed classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.com/code/mogenerator) ([GitHub](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/)).

Comment: While that certainly looks like a cool tool, it doesn't generate the accessors for any of the primitive properties so it doesn't save me any work. In fact, since I already resigned myself to manual editing of the object files, converting to mogenerator would require I yank out all the custom behavior I have in my classes before using it.

Comment: mogenerator does generate accessors for primitive properties. E.g. it will generate a -(int)fileCountValue method for a fileCount integer property. You do not have to rewrite your custom behavior as mogenerator will generate _<classname>.h files with the autogenerated stuff and will leave your <classname>.h files alone. The only thing you will have to do is include the header file and make your class a subclass of _<classname>.

Comment: There is a difference between the scalar values it exposes which are stored within NSNumber objects and the primitive dictionary accessors for entity attributes. However, I dug into the mogenerator templates and was able to modify them to add the declarations I needed, so the tool worked for me after all. Once I verify that I didn't screw up the template, I will probably upload it to the mogenerator github repository.

Comment: I misinterpreted your primitive properties remark. Good to see you found use of mogenerator after all ;-).